Usage of VAULT_PASSWORD in playbook
Considering the following test playbook vault.yaml, with one Ansible Vault encrypted variable:
---
- name: Ansible Vault
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    - name: playbook_action
      prompt: "Select an action to perform:\n
        1) List encrypted variables\n
        2) Update global password\n"
      private: false
  tasks:
    - name: Encrypted Variables
      when: playbook_action in ['1', '1)']
      block:
        - name: Set encrypted variables fact
          ansible.builtin.set_fact:
            encrypted_variables:
              - ansible_password: '{{ ansible_password }}'
          no_log: true

        - name: List encrypted variables
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            var: encrypted_variables

    - name: Global Password
      when: playbook_action in ['2', '2)']
      block:
        - name: Set new global password
          ansible.builtin.pause:
            prompt: Password
            echo: false
          register: password

        - name: Update global password
          ansible.builtin.command:
            cmd: ansible-vault encrypt_string {{ item | quote }}  -n {{ item | quote }}
          environment:
            VAULT_PASSWORD: '{{ password.user_input }}'
          loop:
            - ansible_password
          register: encrypted_variables
          changed_when: true
          no_log: true

        - name: List encrypted variables
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            var: encrypted_variables.results | map(attribute = 'stdout')

While running:
ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass vault.yaml
Vault password:
Select an action to perform:
 1) List encrypted variables
 2) Update global password
: 2

I would expect the playbook to make use of the defined environment VAULT_PASSWORD variable. Instead, I'm prompted to enter a new Vault password, for each variable I want to encrypt. The goal is to define once the new Vault password and use it implicitly into loop.
Edit: the only way I managed to address the issue was by creating a temporary password file:
        - name: Create password file
          ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
            line: '{{ password.user_input }}'
            path: ./password
            mode: '0644'
            create: true

        - name: Update global password
          ansible.builtin.command:
            cmd: ansible-vault encrypt_string {{ item | quote }}  -n {{ item | quote }} --vault-pass-file ./password
          loop:
            - ansible_password
          register: encrypted_variables
          changed_when: true
          no_log: true

        - name: Delete password file
          ansible.builtin.file:
            path: ./password
            state: absent

I would still prefer to use the VAULT_PASSWORD environment variable defined into task.

I don't see any good usage of your playbook?! What is the purpose at all? You don't play with Ansible locally, that's the Multi Process Automation tool. If you need to keep your password, you could simply use env file locally, that's also useful to keep other sensitive data as well, or you could use Ansible Vault. But anyway, i don't see any point on this!

It's not about what Ansible is or whether it's used locally, and yes it's using Ansible Vault. The use case itself is fine except that the OP seems to have implemented a less secure wrapper around the already existing ansible-vault command - and that's where the purpose is unclear yet.

I currently have several variables encrypted into a GitHub repository. The goal of vault.yaml playbook is to allow end-user visualize all encrypted variables, after they have been initially encrypted with the same global password. The second option is an easy way for end-user to rotate the global password and display the new encrypted variables. Eventually I will implement lineinfile replacements, for the encrypted variables.

I don't think lineinfile would be a good solution as you would end up with a YAML file after all. If you encrypt all the variables in the file with the same vault password, consider encrypting the whole file. The downside of it is that you will not know the names of the encrypted variables but the maintenance overhead would be significantly lower. Also, putting the ansible-vault command invocations into a shell script seems to be a simpler and safer solution for the goal you've described - AFAIR ansible-vault has a dedicated command specifically for re-encryption.

Alternatively, you can use ansible-vault-rotate tool that is already doing exactly what you want.

Thank you for the information Alexander. For my use case, the playbook will be easier to work with, for end-user.

I created the related documentation for the above detailed playbook, which explains the usage logic behind. https://axivo.com/k3s-cluster/tutorials/handbook/ansible/


I would expect the playbook to make use of the defined environment VAULT_PASSWORD variable.

Which is not possible by design: this variable is not used by Ansible so I'm not sure what is your expectation based upon. Generally, you have to either provide the password on prompt with --ask-vault-password, or define the location of the password file like you do in the second example (or using the ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE environment variable as per the documentation link above).

Thank you Alexander for the useful information, I will stick with the solution presented into OP.
